# Flutter example not running on Firebase Test lab

Tags: firebase, flutter, flutter-test, firebase-test-lab

I'm trying to set up Firebase test lab instrumentation test with Flutter. I have tried creating a minimal example but haven't been able to run it on the test lab. The example runs fine on my computer when running with `flutter drive`. When looking into the log, I notice that there is an error near the end of the log file which might be the cause of the error `failed to find package com.example.example`

When trying out the example package in https://github.com/flutter/flutter/tree/master/packages/integration_test/example, I can run the tests on the Firebase test lab, so my commands should be correct. I have tried to compare the difference between the integration_test and my example but to no avail.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: If you post your failing matrix-id (e.g. matrix-abcd123456) to the #test-lab channel on Slack, the oncall engineer can take a look at what is causing the failure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out the package not found error is completely unrelated and I needed to put the FlutterActivityTest.java file under src/androidTest/java/package/name folder. Previously, I mistakenly put it in src/androidTest/kotlin/package/name